# Play Framework ReCaptcha with java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, recaptcha

I need to know how to use recaptcha, There is a lib in scala but not in java.

Can you help me with some sample of code in order to understand how to use that lib :

> https://github.com/chrisnappin/play-recaptcha-v2-example/blob/release-2.1/app/controllers/ExampleForm.scala

In java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this in you controller to validate the form:

```
private boolean isRecaptchaValid(String recaptchaKey, String useRecaptcha) {
    String recaptchaSecretKey = configuration.getString("recaptchaSecretKey");

    WSRequest holder = ws.url("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
    holder.setQueryParameter("secret", recaptchaSecretKey);
    holder.setQueryParameter("response", recaptchaKey);

    CompletionStage<JsonNode> jsonPromise = holder.post("").thenApply(WSResponse::asJson);

    JsonNode googleResponse = null;
    try{
        googleResponse = jsonPromise.toCompletableFuture().get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (googleResponse!= null && googleResponse.get("success") != null && googleResponse.get("success").asBoolean()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```